# Apple Numbers : remove rows with blank cells

Tags: ms-office, numbers

I have a tables with some rows with empty cells. I want to remove those rows.

In Excel I can use the "Go To..." command to select blank cells and then i can delete the rows manually. (see this youtube video : https://youtu.be/juNiyixq_oA )

Is there an equivalent way to do it in Numbers ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directly similar method does not exist in Numbers.

However, you can filter out any row with an empty cell in a table creating a filter using the Organize->Filter sidebar window.

Once you get there, choose "Add a Filter" and the name of the column with the empty cells and then, deselect "Blank" in the Quick Filter to appear. The rows corresponding to the empty cells in that column will disappear. You can then copy and paste the contents of the table to a new table and Numbers will only paste the visible cells from the filtered out table.

If there is more than one column with empty cells with the empty cells being in different rows in different columns and you wish to filter out all such rows, create a filter rule for each column in the Organize->Filter sidebar window and choose the "Match All Filters" option in the drop down menu at the top of the sidebar window.